# React native Stripe Connect implementation for customers. Uber similar app

Tags: laravel, react-native, stripe-payments, stripes, payout

I am creating react native app with laravel backend. App is similar to uber where there are two types of users: passenger, drivers. When passengers book a ride they pay ride amount that. I need to transfer passenger paid amount to drivers minus fee. How can this be achieved using stripe connect ?

I tried using stripe connect by I dont understant how to make connected accounts for drivers on my side

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pay drivers, then you have to use Stripe Connect and each driver needs to have a Stripe account. To get started, you need to decide two things:

1. Which type of connected account you want to create (Standard, Express, or Custom). You can learn more about this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts).
2. Which type of charge you want to create (Direct, Destination, or Separate Charges & Transfers). You can learn more about this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges).

If you plan to use Express with Destination Charges, then I recommend following [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide).

Comment: What i dont understand is, I need to create connected account for drivers or is there some kind of iframe or something similar which i open to driver, they fill all required information and I recieve account Id ?

Comment: Everything is explained in the links I shared above. For example [for Express accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts): (i) you create the Stripe account with the API, (ii) you create an Account Link for that specific account, and (iii) you redirect the users to the Account Link URL where they will be able to enter all of their information.